# Visual Studio C# Custom Control property is grayed out

Tags: c#, custom-controls

I have a custom control which works fine until I added the following section for a PointF variable but it shows up as grayed out in the properties list and I can't change the values at design time. See image below.

```
[DefaultValue(0)]
[Description("Gets or sets the jetting sword position")]
public virtual PointF jettingPosition
{
    get
    {
        return jettingCentrePos;
    }
    set
    {
        jettingCentrePos = value;
        Refresh();
    }
}
```

[image]

How do I make this property enabled? I need something like the inherited Location property but the values for X and Y need to be float type.

Answer (score 2):

If you used the type `Point` instead of `PointF` I would say just specify a `TypeConverter` of type `PointConverter` and be done with it.

```
[DefaultValue(0)]
[Description("Gets or sets the jetting sword position")]
[TypeConverter(typeof(PointConverter))]
public virtual PointF jettingPosition
```

However, you will see the error `Object does not match target type.` if you did that. Unfortunately you will need to create your own PointF type converter. Luckily we can just copy the `PointConverter` and change the type to PointF which is what we have here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Drawing;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Reflection;   
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class PointFConverter : TypeConverter {

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType) {
        return ((sourceType == typeof(string)) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType));
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType) {
        return ((destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor)) || base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType));
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value) {
        string str = value as string;
        if (value == null) return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
        str = str.Trim();
        if (str.Length == 0) return null;
        if (culture == null) culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        char ch = culture.TextInfo.ListSeparator[0];
        string[] strArray = str.Split(new char[] { ch });
        int[] numArray = new int[strArray.Length];
        TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(float));
        for (int i = 0; i < numArray.Length; i++) {
            numArray[i] = (int)converter.ConvertFromString(context, culture, strArray[i]);
        }
        if (numArray.Length != 2) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid format");
        return new PointF(numArray[0], numArray[1]);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType) {
        if (destinationType == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("destinationType");
        if (value is Point) {
            if (destinationType == typeof(string)) {
                PointF point = (PointF)value;
                if (culture == null) culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
                string separator = culture.TextInfo.ListSeparator + " ";
                TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(float));
                string[] strArray = new string[2];
                int num = 0;
                strArray[num++] = converter.ConvertToString(context, culture, point.X);
                strArray[num++] = converter.ConvertToString(context, culture, point.Y);
                return string.Join(separator, strArray);
            }
            if (destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor)) {
                PointF point2 = (PointF)value;
                ConstructorInfo constructor = typeof(PointF).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(float), typeof(float) });
                if (constructor != null) return new InstanceDescriptor(constructor, new object[] { point2.X, point2.Y });
            }
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }

    public override object CreateInstance(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IDictionary propertyValues) {
        if (propertyValues == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyValues");
        object xvalue = propertyValues["X"];
        object yvalue = propertyValues["Y"];
        if (((xvalue == null) || (yvalue == null)) || (!(xvalue is float) || !(yvalue is float))) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid property value entry");
        }
        return new PointF((float)xvalue, (float)yvalue);
    }

    public override bool GetCreateInstanceSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context) {
        return true;
    }

    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value, Attribute[] attributes) {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(PointF), attributes).Sort(new string[] { "X", "Y" });
    }

    public override bool GetPropertiesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then you can use this:

```
[DefaultValue(0)]
[Description("Gets or sets the jetting sword position")]
[TypeConverter(typeof(PointFConverter))]
public virtual PointF jettingPosition
```

[image]

Here is more information about custom Type Converters. This specific case covers string to point:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ayybcxe5(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Excellent. That worked perfectly and is something new for me to read up on.